# How do I publicly share full event details with a Google Apps Calendar?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, sharing

So I have a newly-created Google Apps free account, and I would like to make a calendar that is entirely publicly viewable.  I went into Service Settings -> Calendar, and under Outside  - set user ability I selected "Share all information, and outsiders can change calendars":

[image]

Then on the calendar, I clicked on the drop-down arrow in the left menu, selected "Share this Calendar", ticked "Share this Calendar with others", and "Make this calendar public".  I would love to now select from the dropdown "See all event details", but I can't:

[image]
Showing only free/busy would completely defeat the whole purpose of having the calendar, so it's no good...I've tried logging out, clearing cookies, trying a completely different browser, but nothing seems to help.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for people complaining about the time to get this updates, YOU DON'T HAVE TO WAIT, but instead log off and log in again in your accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out the missing ingredient was time.  I went back to it just now and the missing option was there - I don't know how long it took to show up, but if anyone else should bump into this, just wait!

Comment: Missing ingredient for me was time as well. It was only about 5 minutes while Googling for this answer, but I also switched browsers (who knows, that might speed up the wait for others -- give it a shot).

Comment: still no other option showing up for me. what's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that you need to just wait.

Strange how Google Apps are slower to both update settings and get new features. It took weeks before I could change the skin of Gmail once I switched to Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create the public calendar in a Gmail account, grant your Google Apps email access to manage sharing, then log into the Google Apps email and delete the Gmail account from the sharing menu.